# Better site compare to remaining for java

Tags: java

How to go back to same statement in java.(if any exception arise I want to execute from ::  `System.out.println("enter the initial balance");` this statement.

```
try{            
    System.out.println("enter the initial balance");
    bal=scan.nextDouble();  
   }
   catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Enter only numbers" );
 }
```

Comment: You can use a loop: `while(balNotSet){...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to put it in a do while loop and use a boolean to check for an exception:

```
boolean exception;

do {
    exception = false;
    try {
        System.out.println("enter initial balance");
        bal = scan.nextDouble();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        exception = true;
        scan.next(); //discard the input
    }
} while (exception);
```

Comment: above code  is working....

Answer (score 2):

You might use a loop to check if the balance if there is an exception or not.

```
double bal = 0;
while(true)
{
 try
 {
   System.out.println("Enter the balance");
   bal = sc.nextDouble();
   break;
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
  System.out.println("That isn't a number");
  sc.next();//discard the unmatched input
 }
}
```